# Tangent vector to a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

What exactly is a Tangent vector to a geodesic? I see this term is used often but I just can't find a definition for that.

I got stuck at this place in a book:
[image]

Comment: can you add some more details? Maybe notation, where you got stuck and what your math level is

Comment: yes of course, I added the part in the book I'm working in in my question. I have basic differential geometry knowledge (just started), I know what a tangent vector is and I know that, for a geodesic curve $\gamma$, it holds $g(\gamma^{'},\gamma^{'})=const$ but I don't know what a tangent vector to a geodesic is (or maybe I know but I use a different name for it since my differential geometry lecture is not in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is a *purely* notational problem; notation is, as you may already know, sometimes a tricky issue in geometry and related fields. Apologies in advance if it feels like I am going round the houses in my answer.

The first paragraph defines the exponential map at a point $p\in\Sigma$ as
$$\exp:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times \Sigma\to M;\, (r,p)\mapsto c_p(r).
$$

This gives us, for each point $p$ in $\Sigma$ a path $c_p(r)$ that passes through $p$ and is contained in $\Sigma$. That path has one parameter ($r$), which ranges from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$. The vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, when applied to a point $c_p(r_0)$ gives us a vector tangent to $c_p(r_0)$.

Let me rephrase what we know so far: $c_p(\cdot)$ is, as the first paragraph says, a null geodesic. The vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, when applied to a point on the geodesic line, will give us a vector that is tangent to the geodesic. That is the reason why we can speak of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ as a vector tangent to the geodesic.

With regards to the 'null' part, that only means that the vector is lightlike, i.e. that $g_{rr} = 0$. You can find more about space-, time-, and lightlike vectors on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure), and probably on your book.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, do I understand it right, that the vector field $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is only defined on the image of $c_p$?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is kind of 'yes and no'. It's 'yes', in the sense that we have so far used the coordinate $r$ for the geodesics $c_p$. This is the most important part, I'd say.

However, it is also 'no': if we have a chart $U$ for $M$ with coordinates, say $(x,y):\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$, the field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ would be defined outside the geodesics. Said this, I fail to grasp any physical sense it may have (not implying that it hasn't any, just that I know quite little physics).

Comment: Sorry, I lack the knowledge on this topic to properly understand your comment,: if we have a chart on $M$ we would have four coordinates right? so it's just a chart on $\Sigma$? And then in what way is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ defined outside the geodesics? Do we then mean by $r$ just the first local cooridinate on $M$? But if that holds, why can we still conclude $<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}>=0$ outside of geodesics?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot make sense of it within the margins of a comment, and I might probably give a distorted idea of things. For the time being, I would say it is safer to think of the coordinate $r$ and thus of the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ as things defined only on geodesics. Veering off the geodesic path will likely divert you from your current goals, which is far from my intention.

Comment: ok, thank you again! I don't want to be pushy, it's just that as I understand is, in this part of the book they already use ∂∂r not only on geodesics, because they use it on V, the neighborhood of q with V\subset M right?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. At the end of the day you can think of $r$ as the 'geodesic' coordinate in this context. The map $\psi_u$ has been constructed so that different values of $r$ give different points of the same geodesic (leaving the rest untouched). Change any of the other coordinates and you are no longer moving through geodesics.

Comment: Hm, ok.. to be honest I don't really understand your comment but I have no concrete questions I just have to deal longer with the topic (I also don't really understand the definition of the local coordinates yet) so .. but thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You're most welcome! Best wishes ^^